# How to define a value for footer in gridview

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

The footer is a string, if i put in 'value' works fine, but in footer give me a error:

> trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'showFooter' => true,
        'footerRowOptions'=>['style'=>'font-weight:bold;text-decoration: underline;'],
        'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'XXX',
                'format' => 'currency',
                'value' => function($model) use ($anoFilter) {
                        return $model->getValorTotalParcelas($anoFilter);
                }, 
                'footer' => function($model) use ($anoFilter) {
                    return $model->getValorTotal($anoFilter);
                }
            ]
        ])
```

getValorTotal

```
public function getValorTotal($ano = null){
    $titulo = new FinlegadoTitulo();
    $valorTotalParcelas = $titulo->getValorTotalparcelasByClienteAndStatus(null,false,false,$ano);
    return $valorTotalParcelas;
}
```

and

```
public function getValorTotalparcelasByClienteAndStatus($clienteId = null, $aberta = false, $vencida = false,$ano = null){
    $parcelas = FinlegadoTituloParcela::find()->joinWith(['finlegadoTitulo']);
    if ($clienteId) {
        $parcelas->andWhere(['finlegado_cliente_id' => $clienteId]);
    }
    if ($ano) {
        $parcelas->andWhere('YEAR(tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.data_pagamento_previsto) = ' . $ano);
    }
    if($aberta){
        $parcelas->andWhere(['tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.pago' => null]);
        $parcelas->andWhere("tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.status <> 'C'");
        $parcelas->andWhere("tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.status <> 'D'");
        if($vencida){
            $parcelas->andWhere('tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.data_pagamento_previsto < (NOW() - interval '.Yii::$app->params['delay_inadimplencia'].' day)');
        }else{
            $parcelas->andWhere('tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.data_pagamento_previsto >= NOW()');
        }
    } else {
        $parcelas->andWhere(['tbl_finlegado_titulo_parcela.pago' => true]);
    }

    return $parcelas->sum('valor_parcela');
}
```

The code above works fine

Comment: can you post from model  $model->getValorTotal($anoFilter);  method code

Comment: can u test this when u set footer : return (string)  $model->getValorTotal($anoFilter);

Comment: But what kind of result give you $titulo->getValorTotalparcelasByClienteAndStatus(null,false,false,$ano); please provide the related code or a var_dump of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this doc   http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html
For footer you can't use the anomymous function but only the string value.

then you can calculate yuor value out of the gridview and the assign to the footer

```
$parkFooter = $model->getValorTotal($anoFilter);

 ........
'columns' => [
        [
            'attribute' => 'XXX',
            'format' => 'currency',
            'value' => function($model) use ($anoFilter) {
                    return $model->getValorTotalParcelas($anoFilter);
            }, 
            'footer' => $parkFooter
```

Comment: Your reply get me a idea for solution.